# Стоит ли делать глобальное подключение к БД в Java EE?

Tags: mysql, java-ee, jdbc

Есть ли целесообразность сделать одно подключение к БД при старте сервера? То бишь сделать синглтон который будет один раз выполнять подключение к БД при старте сервера. И закрывать его при остановке.

Comment: как и со всеми остальными синглтонами - нет

Answer (score 2):

Нужно при старте делать пул подключений и увеличивать/уменьшать количество коннектов по необходимости.

Comment: не стоит того. очень сложно. + могут быть проблемы с определением пула. Нашел более легкое решение.

Answer (score -1):

Решение состоит в том что бы создавать для каждого пользователя одно подключение к БД и хранить его в сессии. По истечении времени сессии закрывать соединение в слушателе.

Comment: Если будет 50 пользователей, то будет 50 подключений, даже если юзер ничего с базой не делает?

Comment: @Suvitruf да. Если брать пул то будет такая же штука.Создавать одно глобальное подключение тоже не вариант. Если будет много пользователей то это скажется на работоспособности.

Comment: @Tsyklop имеет смысл выделять из пула подключение хотя бы на каждый запрос, требующий работу с БД. Держать на каждого пользователя по соединению - это дикий перебор, если планируется возможность пользования сервисом больше, например, 100 пользователей разом.

Comment: @Regent почему же перебор? оно само закроется через 30 минут если юзер активен не будет. а запросы будут идти регулярно. В пуле появляется много нюансов. нужно постоянно сделать за их количеством. Не исключайте тот факт что имеет место многопоточность.

Comment: @Tsyklop сотни библиотек уже для этого есть (я про пулы). "Если брать пул то будет такая же штука". Не будет, так как соединения переиспользуются. У нас, к примеру, хватает пула из 10 подключений на сотни/тысячи пользователей.

Comment: @Tsyklop потому что сотни/тысячи одновременных подключений к БД, которые, надо полагать, бОльшую часть времени будут простаивать - это как-то странно. И это если SQL-сервер вообще сможет поддерживать такое количество подключений к себе, не говоря уж о системных ресурсах, выделенных на эти подключения

Comment: @Suvitruf какая библиотека? подскажите пожалуйста. И правильно я понимаю. создать 10 подключений и выбирать из рандомно какое-то для юзера?

Comment: @Tsyklop в dbcp был `BasicDataSource`. там вроде встроен уже пул. Ничего извлекать не надо и т.п. Он сам за всем следит.

Comment: @Suvitruf тобишь мне просто надо получать конекшен и все? а либа сама будет следит за их количеством и какой дать юзеру? да?

Comment: @Tsyklop что-то вроде того. Там только в самом начале настроить штуку эту нужно и всё.

Comment: @Tsyklop создаёте пул (указав адрес сервера, логин и пароль, а также, при желании, размер пула), после чего запрашиваете соединения из него. Как только подключение больше не нужно - вызываете у него `close`, благодаря чему оно возвращается обратно в пул.